# Check and match between two arrays without nested loop?

Tags: javascript, data-structures

I have two arrays and I want to check and match values between two arrays but without using nested for-loop. Is it possible?

```
ISO system date:   [ '2020', '06', '27' ]
Date from System:  [ '06', '27', '20' ]
```

I tried this:

```
function getFormat(isoDateArr, sysDateArr, sysDateFormat) {
    for (let i = 0; i < isoDateArr.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < sysDateArr.length; j++) {
            if (isoDateArr[i].includes(sysDateArr[j])) {
                createFormat(sysDateArr, sysDateFormat, i, j);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But not able to think of how can I achieve it without nested loop?

Comment: what if month and day is switched?

Comment: @NinaScholz Thats already taken care

Comment: If you need `i` and `j` (and while it is unknown what `createFormat()` actually does, it is very visible that `i` and `j` are both passed to it as arguments), you need some kind of loop. In fact `includes()` is a loop too.

Comment: What should `getFormat()` do in the first place? It gets two arrays and an unknown third parameter. Then it tests every element in the first array if it is found in the second array - and `break`s  at the first match, after calling `createFormat()` with the indexes of the matches. And then returns `undefined`/nothing... -> [mcve]

Comment: @tevemadar updated question with more code

Comment: @Andreas 3rd param is copy of 2nd param

Comment: @Andreas I am trying to get system format from system like if it is "mm-dd-yyyy" or if it is "yyyy-mm-dd" and then creating iso date for user entered date

Answer (score 1):

You could build real ISO date strings and compare.

```js
const
    isEqual = (iso, system) => `20${iso.join('-')}` === `20${system[2]}-${system[0]}-${system[1]}`,
    iso = ['20', '06', '27'],
    system = ['06', '27', '20'];


console.log(isEqual(iso, system));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by building datetime objects using these arrays and them for checking the quality convert the datetime toDateString:

```
var isoArray = [ '2020', '06', '27' ];
var systemArray = [ '06', '27', '20' ];
var isoArrayDate = new Date(isoArray.join("-"));
console.log(systemArrayDate.toDateString() == isoArrayDate.toDateString());
```